# Kotlin / Java equivalent of Swift, Dictionary / HashMap with null value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

In Swift, when I want in Firebase to "move" data from table A to table B I need to delete it from table A and write it on table B, and do both actions with one transaction only, using a Dictionary, like this:

`let tableADict = ["tableA/someID/" : NSNull()]
let tableBDict = ["tableB/someID/" : (someValue)]`

Then I merge both "instructions" into one dictionary and use the `updateChildValues` from Firebase. Doing that I can delete from table A and write on table B.

The problem is trying to do the same in Kotlin, when I try to put null as value on a `HashMap<String, Any>` I get `@throws kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type`

**My question is:** How can I make a structure like Swift Dictionary that will delete from table A and write on table B on the same `updateChildValues` in Kotlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to put nulls as values in a HashMap in Kotlin, define it like this:

```
HashMap<String, Any?>
```

The question mark says that the value may be optionally null.